# One of the 'Organisation' or 'Organisations'

Tags: grammatical-number

I am writing an essay and stuck with the following sentence.

> One of the non-profit organisation that we worked with...

Should organisation be plural or singular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organisation must be **plural** here.

This is because when you say

> one of ***_*__**

you mean

> one *of many*.

At least it would mean one of two.

So out of the many organisations, you're referring to one.

And the usage is therefore "one of the non-profit organisations"